# Why does my ImageIcon disappear after using setLocation() on JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, imageicon

I want to move a JFrame window containing a GIF across my screen, but when I try the following:

```
icon = new ImageIcon(spritePath);
frame.add(new JLabel(icon));
frame.setSize(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
frame.setVisible(true);
for (int i = 0; i < screenSize.getWidth() - icon.getIconWidth(); i++) {
    frame.setLocation(i, yMidpoint);
    Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

My window moves but the gif doesn't show up. I also tried increasing the sleep delay to a higher number like 1000 and that didn't work. And the gif shows when I don't move it with setLocation(), so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: do you have frame.setBound , or setVisible  ? show please you code

Comment: @AmerAlMunajjed I have frame.setVisible(true), as shown in the code snippet. [Here is my full code if you need it](https://pastebin.com/v45PZcpL)

Comment: You should be using a Swing `Timer` for that

Comment: `My window moves but the gif doesn't show up` multiple possible reasons; 1. You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread (with your `while-loop`) preventing the window contents from being painted; 2. `icon = new ImageIcon(spritePath);` is failing silently and not actually loading the image, use [`ImageIO.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) instead, it will throw an exception if the image can't be loaded for some reason.  As a starting suggestion, remove the `while-loop` and check to see if the image is been presented.

Comment: `frame.setSize(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());` is ill-advised as windows also have decorations which are rendered inside the window (so the content area is smaller then the window size).  Better to use an appropriate layout manager and `pack` to pack the window around the content itself

Comment: Another point: there should almost always be *just one `JFrame` per app*. If you need to create extra windows, they should be of a different class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was that `Thread.sleep()` prevents the window contents from being painted if it is run in the same thread that the JFrame is created, so I simply had it run the code in a new thread and now it works.